# How to pass space to Cobra CLI string slice flag?

Tags: powershell, go, go-cobra

I am using a StringSliceP from the [Pflag libraray](https://github.com/spf13/pflag/blob/master/string_slice.go#L143) accept a list of strings as CLI arguments.

I am calling the Go application from the Windows Command Prompt.

I would like some of the strings of the list to contain a (`"`) double quote character, but I have not been able to do this.

Escaping the quotes does not work:

```
goapp.exe --string-slice-list "a\"b",c,d,e
```

Expected result: `[]string{"a\"b", "c", "d", "e"}`

Actual result: `Error: invalid argument "a\"\\b,c,d,e" for "--string-slice-list" flag: parse error on line 1, column 1: bare " in non-quoted-field`

Doubling up the quotes does not work:

```
goapp.exe --string-slice-list "a""b",c,d,e
```

Expected result: `[]string{"a\"b", "c", "d", "e"}`

Actual result: `Error: invalid argument "a\"b,c,d,e" for "--string-slice-list" flag: parse error on line 1, column 1: bare " in non-quoted-field`

Comment: Did you checked the PowerShell escape character? Because it's different then others.

Comment: Changing the question to say Windows Command Prompt rather than PowerShell as I did the above testing in PowerShell.  Apologies for the incorrect information.  The same problem exists in PowerShell using the PowerShell escape character (`\``).  This seems like a problem in how the Cobra/Pflags library interprets the arguments.

Comment: `bare " in non-quoted-field` seems to be an error related to Go's `"encoding/csv"` library.  It looks like Cobra/Pflags makes use of it [here](https://github.com/spf13/pflag/blob/85dd5c8bc61cfa382fecd072378089d4e856579d/string_slice.go#L5).

Comment: it is not doubling the quotes around on those systems ? something like `""a"b,c...""` i dont remember well this pos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it from a Windows command prompt:

```
goapp.exe --string-slice-list \"a\"\"b\",c,d,e
```

yields `[a"b c d e]` and

```
goapp.exe --string-slice-list \"a\\\"\"b\",c,d,e
```

does `[a\"b c d e]` (I’m not sure which one you actually want).

The reason for this is, as has been pointed out, that the [Pflag library](https://github.com/spf13/pflag/) makes use of the Go standard library [encoding/csv](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv) supporting the format described in [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.html). If we refer to section 2 from paragraphs 5, 6 and 7:

> If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
> double quotes may not appear inside the fields.

> Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
> should be enclosed in double-quotes.

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.